# Mongoose retrived data is empty because of async calls

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having a problem assuming because of the asyn nature of mongoDB.
assuming i have schema like this :

```
const TopicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String,unique:true},
    sub_topic:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Topic'}] 
});
```

i want to make a function to return an array with the ids in sub_topic.
i tryied this with no success:

```
let subs;
subs = getSubs(req.params.id)
console.log('returned subs', subs)

function getSubs (dadID) {
    let subs = [];
    Topic.findById(dadID,function(err,res){
      console.log('res : ',res);
      subs=subs.concat(res.sub_topic);
      console.log('subs after concat:',subs)
    })
    console.log('subs after Topic.find:',subs)
    return subs;
  }
```

as you can see in the result.
the subs after concat is correct. but

> the call of the return subs is happening before the query is returned and fires up the callback function i gave it

result is :

```
subs after Topic.find: []
returned subs []
res :  { sub_topic:
   [ 5bc9c894740a2a52f906a95c,
     5bc9c894740a2a52f906a95f,
     5bc9c894740a2a52f906a960 ],
  _id: 5bc9c894740a2a52f906a95b,
  name: 'A',
  __v: 0 }
subs after concat: [ 5bc9c894740a2a52f906a95c,
  5bc9c894740a2a52f906a95f,
  5bc9c894740a2a52f906a960 ]
```

what if i just want to return the full doc as a return.
can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it `async`

```
let subs;
subs = getSubs(req.params.id)
  .then((subs) => {
    // do something with subs or the topic
  });

async function getSubs (dadID) {
    let subs = [];
    const topic = await Topic.findById(dadID);
    subs=subs.concat(topic.sub_topic);
    return subs; // or return the topic
}
```

Comment: Yeah just make sure to check if `topic` is `null` and wrap it in a `try catch` block!

Comment: what if i wanted to go deeper with recursion to each ID i get in the subs to retrive their id. while doing this. i got back a Promise <pending> in the returned value from the function :\ can i make it wait for the recursion calls to finish too before returning?

Comment: @AlmogHazan open a new question for this one, and post your code and details of the problem ;)